# Under what circumstances are SQL Server triggers executed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

The database I'm working on has a trigger which calls a stored procedure which takes 42 seconds to run if I do an `UPDATE` using T-SQL. If I edit the row in SQL Server Management Studio, the row updates instantly. Triggers are executed in the edit window as well as on T-SQL UPDATES, aren't they?

The SQL code in the stored procedure comes back instantly if I run it directly or call it using EXEC, the only circumstances when it runs slowly are when the trigger is called by an UPDATE statement.

Comment: Not able to understand your question.What do you really want to achieve? Please provide more details. Provide trigger syntax also

Comment: Depends what the trigger does. How many rows are affected? What does the stored procedure do? and so on.

Comment: If you edit a row in SQL Server Management Studio are triggers tripped?

Comment: Yes that just sends an update statement when you move off the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how the trigger was set up, Triggers will only run on Update, Delete and Insert statements (Depending which of the three are chosen) On the table it is set against.

Could you give the code used to create the trigger?

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[refreshSubscriptionAddressBlock]
ON [dbo].[ADDRESS]
FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;                                             
 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)
the code to be run
GO

Comment: Ok so then yes, if you edit (update) a row in the Address table the trigger will be 'triggered'

Comment: Lovely that's what I thought but at this point I'm doubting myself thanks.   Now I've just got to figure out why the stored procedure takes 42 seconds to run only with t-sql updates.   Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

```
These triggers run after an insert, update or delete on a table
```

[click here for details about different type of triggers and demo for triggers](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-Sql-Server)

Comment: I know the different types of triggers, that's not what I'm asking, I'm asking 

 If you edit a row in SQL Server Management Studio are triggers tripped?